# Roboelectric slow and gives warnings

Tags: android, testing, robolectric

This is my first time using Roboelectric.
Writing my first test which is just a simple test asserting the title
of the Activity takes about 18s to execute and gives me the following warnings:

```
WARNING: no system properties value for "ro.control_privapp_permissions"
WARNING: no system properties value for "ro.crypto.state"
WARNING: no system properties value for "ro.crypto.type"
```

What are those warnings? and even if I ignore the warnings, should it really
take 18s to execute this small test?

This is the test:

```
@Test
public void titleIsCorrect() throws Exception {
    Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    assertTrue(activity.getTitle().toString().equals("Title"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

The warning is known issue and discussed on the Robolectric GitHub. There should be a solution for this soon.

About the long start, it is how Robolectric works. On the first Robolectric test it loads resources/assets/etc and then runs tests noticeably fast.